# My MBP 2011 won't go to slep when AC is plugged in

Tags: sleep-wake

Since a few days, my MBP (15" early 2011 with 10.9.4) won't go to sleep when I close the lid and the AC is plugged in.

I fixed the permissions, repaired the SSD via disk utility, searched in the console to find an issue referenced, try to simulate the closing action with a magnet (the screen goes dark).

Since my computer is not power nap capable, I don't understand what's going on.

It goes well when I unplug it.

Comment: @ecnepsnai `try to simulate the closing action with a magnet (the screen goes dark)` the apple goes dark and so th screen ;)

Comment: But it doesn't when you close the lid, without the magnet?  It stays on?

Comment: @ecnepsnai when I close the lid, it does dark

Comment: But when you open it back up, it's right back where you left off?  It doesn't ask you to login, right?

Comment: @ecnepsnai yes it does ! (I ask it as soon as the screen goes off) but the fans are still working and the console log is still written so it's not sleeping

Comment: In System Preferences -> Energy Saver -> Power Adapter Tab is the Computer Sleep set to never?

Comment: @ecnepsnai yes, but no, that doesn't fix the issue :(

Comment: In System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> General Tab do you have the "Require Password after sleep" to to "immediately"?

Comment: @ecnepsnai yes !